# Word Suggestion: Subsequent Events

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase which would identify a book index that would describe "what happened next" to some of the individuals mentioned in the book. "Dramatis personae" doesn't do it because the book is non-fiction. "List of Characters" won't do it because not all the characters are listed. It's not properly an index because there's no reference to the text, just a short paragraph describing what happened to the principal individuals after the events mentioned in the text. This is often seen in film. I'm looking for suggestions.

Aftermath?

Comment: 'Aftermath' is very often used of post-disaster scenarios and for that and other reasons (highfalutin) doesn't work too well. A simple heading  'What happened next' is very common, probably over-common.

Comment: Maybe *Epilogue*.  // This would be a good question at Writers.SE, I think.  You might want to delete this and post it there.

Comment: [Classic Greek and Elizabethan plays often included **epilogues** to explain the **later fates of the characters**. An actor would step forward and speak directly to the audience, offering commentary on the story and dispensing morals, if any were to be found in the tale. Note that **the epilogue, in this respect, is the exact opposite of the prologue and the preface**. Since then, the epilogue has naturally evolved. Today, **this kind of wrap-up is very rarely used** in novels.](https://blog.reedsy.com/what-is-an-epilogue/) Essentially, we don't do it much now, so we don't need a name for it.

Comment: An *epilogue* is the heading that would appear above additional text being added after the end of a novel to indicate additional comments or conclusions to that of the main body of the book.  Like in a movie, when you see additional things happening during or after the credits rolling or written comments that say what happened to depicted characters later on in life, that's an *epilogue*.

Comment: I don't remember anything at the end of *Breaking Bad* telling us about how Saul would go on to star in his own TV series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Epilogue usually refers to events that wrap up after the climax of a story.